# How ext4 File system is changing directory entry structure form linear to Htree?

Tags: filesystems, storage, driver, linux-device-driver, ext4

I have tried some experiments in ext4 fs, when i have created few directories/file. these files are stored in linear directory (struct  ext4_dir_entry_2)  array in directory entry list. But when i created more files(5000 files) the directory entry list is updated to Hash tree. I was able to get information using "debugfs" and validate whole date with hexdump for the device.

Q. But i am still not clear how hash tree works for storing directory entries?

Q. At what point exactly it is updated (linear entry to hashtree entry) and how it is updated in  Linux kernel?

Q. I am trying to do understand htree directory entry list  from https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Hash_Tree_Directories,  but i am not able to  understand   the mapping of  directory entry to hash tree?

Q. How a particular entry is traversed through intermediate blocks with hash key?